# sha256 encrypt and decrypt the string in c#

Tags: c#

Below is my code for encrypting a string using SHA256.

```
SHA256CryptoServiceProvider x1 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] bs1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
bs1 = x1.ComputeHash(bs1);
System.Text.StringBuilder s1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

foreach (byte b in bs1)
{
    s1.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
}

Console.WriteLine(s1.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Can any one help me decrypt the resulting string using SHA256?

Comment: SHA256 is a **one-way** [hashing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). It is not an encryption algorithm; you can't decrypt it, you can merely encrypt the same bytes again and compare the hashes. Note that hashing algorithms are 100% the correct way to go for storing passwords. You should never be able to decrypt a user's password.

Comment: You're essentially asking something like "how do I uncook an egg?"

Comment: @John Gosh I'd love to get the answer to that question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are essentially generating a *checksum*, not encrypting that text. This answer regarding [storing passwords as hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51961121/336648) should help clarify what that means.

You can't *decrypt* a hashed value, but you could compare it to another known value to see if it matches. That known value might be the result of hashing a password, for example, or a known hash from a *rainbow table*.

If you actually want to encrypt and be able to decrypt data, you should perhaps look into AES-encryption instead.